# Почему не обновился ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Исходный массив:

```
$scope.ms = [1,2,3,4];
```

Добавляем еще один элемент:

```
$scope.ms.push(5);
$scope.$apply();
```

Вывод в HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="id in ms">
    <span>{{id}}</span>
</div>
```

Почему-то в шаблоне не отображается 4 элемент массива (число 5).
Есть ли другие способы динамического добавления элементов в `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Могли бы подробнее рассказать, откуда вы вызываете код
$scope.ms.push(5);
$scope.$apply();

Comment: Как-то странно вы используете $apply. Замените тогда уж его на $scope.$digest(); Если хочется использовать $apply, то код лучше переписать так

    $scope.$apply(function(){ // меняете массив здесь });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правильный ответ**: `ng-repeat` вызывает исключение в работе, в момент выполнения `$scope.ms.push(5)`, это можно увидеть в консоли браузера -`[ngRepeat:dupes]`. В простом массиве нужно указать уникальное поле, по которому `ng-repeat` будет отличать элементы друг от друга. Для этого есть спец. переменные и параметры `ng-repeat`

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in ms track by $index">
    {{ item }}
  </li>  
</ul>
```

В данном случае мы говорим - "используй `$index`" - индекс нашего массива.
И да, при работе со `$scope`, `$apply` использовать не нужно.

Вот пример работы:
https://jsbin.com/viwepocuye/edit?html,js,output

Comment: для приведенных данных такой ошибки быть не может. потому что все элементы уникальны.

Comment: только при первой инициализации, но при попытке добавить элемент будет вызвано исключение, это всегда так. Поэтому я описал это в ответе (в вопросе пример динамического изменения массива). Поэтому простая процедура не работает, это нужно знать при работе с angular. И поэтому один пример работает, а другой нет.

Comment: При попытке добавить элемент `5` в массив `[1,2,3,4]` - ошибки не будет. именно этот случай у автора вопроса.

Comment: да, это так, в этом случае ошибку вызывает `$scope.$apply ` -[$rootScope:inprog]. Но рассуждения и ответы пошли "не в ту сторону". Хотелось обратить на это внимание и не более.

Answer (score 0):

Оно должно само обновлять все `$apply` не нужно.

Модификация примера из местной справки нормально работает:

Шаблон:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example43-production</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>  
</head>

<body ng-app="scopeExample">
  <div class="show-scope-demo">
  <div ng-controller="GreetController">
    Hello {{name}}!
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ListController">
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}} from {{department}}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
  .controller('GreetController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $rootScope.department = 'Angular';
  }])
  .controller('ListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['Igor', 'Misko', 'Vojta'];
    $scope.names.push('Another One'); //Вот здесь добавляем еще одного.
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

[Онлайн тест.](http://plnkr.co/edit/TVr8nz2ZtBXBYER0OzWq?p=preview)

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда из этой же оперы, почему вот так добавляется в массив: `$scope.messages[500] = {
                    dialog: "534_544",
                    from: "538",
                    message: "sss",
                    read: "0",
                    time: "528852706",
                    to: "546"
                };`  А через `$scope.messages.push();` - не добавляет?

Comment: Ну первая строчка просто [инициализирует 500ый объект в массиве](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), а вторая ничего и не добавит, там аргумента то нет внутри `push();`